# How to use a angular value into ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html

I have added my code here. I want to use `{{gname}}` in `ng-repeat`. What's the proper syntax for this?

```
<div class="groupvalues"  ng-repeat="gname in groupname">
{{gname}}
<div class="subvalues"  ng-repeat="gvalues in groupvalues['{{gname}}']">
    {{gvalues}}                         
</div>
```

Comment: So what error or problem you face? Can you share a fiddle showing an example?

Comment: `gvalues in groupvalues[gname]` should work

Comment: I am not getting any errors but the particular values are not printing..I dont have fiddle..

Comment: Yes its working.. Thanks Huey..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
<div class="groupvalues"  ng-repeat="gname in groupname">
  {{gname}}

  <div class="subvalues"  ng-repeat="gvalues in groupvalues[gname]">
      {{gvalues}}                         
  </div>

</div>
```